# Mid 2014 macbook pro vs mid 2015 macbook pro?

Tags: performance, apple

So I'm currently standing between two choices of macbook pro's. My need is to be able to hook up my macbook via thunderbolt 2 to a dock, and from the dock connect it to a monitor and obtain 4k@60Hz (+ other peripherals). I aim to use this for Xcode, general programming (data science and AI), Matlab, Eclipse, R, Python and watch videos in 4k, thus any sort of lag or klick-delay is very undesirable.

I don't care much about the haptic track pad and esthetics. Also the amount of storage is not important either since I use external SSD or NAS.

Which of the following should I choose, all things (except price) considered?

**Macbook Pro Retina 15'' mid 2015:**

- Intel core i7 @ 2.5 GHz
- 16 GB @ 1600 MHz DDR3
- 512 GB flash SSD
- Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB

or:

**Macbook Pro Retina 15'' mid 2014:**

- Intel core i7 4870HQ QuadCore @ 2.5 GHz (3.7 GHz turbo boost)
- 16 GB @1600 MHz DDR3L
- 240 GB flash SSD
- NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M 2GB GDDR5 +
  Intel Iris Pro 1536MB

To me, the 2014 version seem to be better, but I feel like I'm missing something that the specs aren't covering. Also the 2014 model currently has 0 bids while the 2015 has like 50 bids. Why does the 2015 seem to be more attractive to people if the 2014 has better specs?

Comment: One has the nVidia graphics and the other doesn't? Maybe that's the appeal?

Comment: Does not explain the total lack of interest  in the 2014 model by the general population.